# Wordpress on Appengine

Tags: java, php, wordpress, google-app-engine, quercus

I've been using Appengine to host my site. Now i'm thinking of building the site with wordpress, for a few reasons. Does anyone know how to run a wordpress site on appengine?
I read a couple of blogs but could not understand completely. Anu suggestions?

Comment: Please add the links to the blogs you had problems to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Currently wordpress isn't supported on GAE because of the Wordpress backend (PHP).

I suggest you to switch to another hosting provider with PHP and MySQL support, use the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086465/blog-engine-for-google-app-engine or roll your own.

Anyways, its your call... but i strongly suggest you not to try to fit PHP software on GAE, it 's not suited for that.